# Организация работы с буфером

Tags: массивы, алгоритм

Ситуация такая. 
Есть буфер, - допустим, такой

```
myVar: array[1..40000] of char;
```

и есть процедура

```
procedure myProc(var Arr: array of char; var BytesRecieved);
```

Задача - чтоб после выполнения процедуры буфер был заполнен. Проблема: процедура вызывается из библиотеки(нет возможности ковырять) и записывает от 38000 до 42000 байт. Буфер тоже изменять нельзя.

Пока вижу решение в дополнительном буфере на 43k of char, запускать процедуру на него и далее перекидывать излишки в начало и потом записывать в @myAdditionalBuffer[BytesOverflow]. НО: блин, мне не нравится введение переменной в 43кб =(

Может, у кого есть более оптимальная идея?

[код на делфи для удобства, мне абстрактное описание действий нужно]

**UPD [решено]** в FormCreate в поток забивается 40000 нулей, каждые 5 сек чистится+остаток пишется в начало. Решение не идеальное, но, может, кому пригодится) По крайней мере, оно работает и глюков не наблюдаю.

```
type MyStream = class
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  LastReadPos: integer;
  end;
var MStr: MyStream;
    Buf: array[1..40000] of char;
    AddBuf: array[1..42000] of char;
[...]
myProc(AddBuf, BytesRead);
MStr.Stream.Position :=  MStr.Stream.Size;
MStr.Stream.WriteBuffer(AddBuf[0], BytesRead);
MStr.Stream.Position := MStr.LastReadPos;
MStr.Stream.ReadBuffer(Buf, 40000);
inc(MStr.LastReadPos, 40000);
[...]
```

Comment: А что произойдет если размер буфера меньше, чем объем данных, которые может вернуть процедура?

Comment: Ничего хорошего - Access Violation, или программа затрет какие-нибудь свои данные и будет хромать дальше. Вообще, по логике, многие ф-ции принимают размер входного буфера и если его не хватает, то выдают сообщение об ошибке. И, возможно, заполняют его насколько это возможно.

Comment: А процедурка умная, - я не в курсе, какой там механизм, но безо всяких проблем получал BytesRecieved = 41562. Может, сама sizeof проверяет. И да, она принимает размер буфера, но что-то я с трудом соображаю, как его использует)) разброс до 5% при любом значении.

Comment: Я предлагаю вернуться к тому, что было изначально. Речь ведь шла про работу с LAME? По <a href=http://www.fi.muni.cz/~qruzicka/Smid/man.htm>инструкции</a> там все регламентировано. А вот и <a href=http://users.hol.gr/~dzach/vox/lame/Example.cpp>пример использования</a>

Comment: Да, это Lame, но с файлами у меня и так все хорошо. Только дело обстоит так, что мне нужно на кажджый вызов возвращать ровно отданное количество данных) У меня работа с несколькими потоками и предшествующей+дальнейшей обработкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нормально для таких целей используются расширяемые буфера. Это например потоковый стек. Резервируется регион памяти без аллокации, в начале его выделяется буфер исходного размера. Далее при переполнении буфера обрабатывается фолт - выделяется несколько страниц, к которым произошло обращение. Реализация привязана к платформе и моду, так что не приемлимо для описания скриптом(сделает код не переносимым). Так в NT U-mode это регистрация VEH. В другой оси этого функционала нет(в линуксах именно изза не переносимости обработка исключений сделана крайне криво).

Comment: Спасибо за намек на поток =) Ось будет серверная винда, но неизвестно больше ничего, поэтому просто потоком реализовал.

Comment: http://indy-vx.narod.ru/Mm.zip

(c) wasm.ru